# Check if the user is a fan of my facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook

I used to use the flowing code to check if the user is a fan of my page or not while he is on my facebook page. Now I want to check if the user is a fan of my facebook page while he is on my WEBSITE.

```
<?php
            $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
            list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
            $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

            if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
                echo "You are not a fan!";
            } else {
                echo "Welcome back fan!";
            }
    ?>
```

I read through the facebook documentation, but I was not able to find suitable answer.
Help ?
I do not want to deal with any application permissions with facebook. How can I approach this through only php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not get `page` details if visiting application not in Page Tab.

You may achieve that with simple FQL query to [`page_fan` table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) (knowing the id of the Facebook Page of course):

```
SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=PAGE_ID
```

Or by querying Graph API for [`likes` connection of `user` object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/PAGE_ID
```

Both of those ways require `user_likes` permission granted by user.

To get the same details for user's friends ask for `friends_likes` permission and substitute `me/me()` with friend id.

**Update:** (just to describe what you asked in comments)
There are cases that requiring `user_likes` may be unnecessary due to nature of flow, if you only need to know that user will/need to like some URL and/or Facebook Page.

You may do so by [subscribing (`FB.subscribe`)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to `edge.create` event which will be triggered once user will like the page (for un-like there is `edge.remove` event).

Beware that this is only reliable in cases user didn't liked that content before since `edge.create` only fired on time of user's action.

Comment: Thank you for your response this helps me a lot. So I understand that I will not be able to check if the user is a fan or not with my facebook page (not application) without his/her permission(s) to his/her personal information. I have been in many websites where they force the users to like a specific page or multiple pages in order to view their contents and when I like those pages the website would refresh and view its contents to me without asking my permissions to my facebook information. How would I do such thing ?

Comment: @user1348777, I've updated my answer providing additional details.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. The user click like one time and he can view the site as much as he wants. Now what is the code for that ?

Answer (score 3):

A better approach to the problem is:

```
// to generate user access token after the user is logged in
$USER_ACCESS_TOKEN = $facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();

$isFan = curl("https://api.facebook.com/method/pages.isFan?format=json&access_token=" . $USER_ACCESS_TOKEN . "&page_id=" . $FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID);

        function curl($url) {

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }
```