# How to ask user to like facebook fan page to make download button visible?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to create page in which there is a download link. which is only visible to users who have liked my fan page at facebook. Otherwise it show like button.

I am using the following code but it

```
  <?php

include_once("php/src/facebook.php");

    // Create our Application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => '354967071210221',
      'secret' => 'APP_Secret',
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

// Return you the Page like status
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];

if($like_status)
{
    echo 'User Liked the page';
    // Place some content you wanna show to user

}else{
    echo 'User do not liked the page';
    // Place some content that encourage user to like the page
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete. Could you tell us what are the results you're getting?

Comment: i am always getting User do not liked the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this info using FQL queries

1) Find out your page_id

```
SELECT page_id, pic FROM page WHERE username="grasphub"
```

(It says that your page_id is 354967071210221)

2) Check if user has liked your page using this query

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=354967071210221 AND uid = me()
```

This query will return empty result if user did not like your page yet.

So, your code will be:

```
include_once("php/src/facebook.php");

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '354967071210221',
    'secret' => 'APP_Secret',
    'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) { // Checks if there is already a logged in user
    try {
        $result = $facebook->api( array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => 'SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=354967071210221 AND uid = me()',
        ));

        if (!empty($result[0]['page_id'])) {
            echo 'User Liked the page';
        } else {
            echo 'User do not liked the page';
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
} else { //Ask for bare minimum login
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$login_url);
}
```

Comment: i am using it but it is giving error 
Notice: Undefined variable: facebook in E:\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\fb\index.php on line 6

Fatal error: Call to a member function getAccessToken() on a non-object in E:\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\fb\index.php on line 6

Comment: I edited code above. Of course, you should create $facebook instance first.

Comment: Now it is giving this error
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 190: Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error. thrown in E:\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\fb\php\src\base_facebook.php on line 1238

Comment: I edited code once again, and can you check if you use valid appId and secret? You shouldn't just copy-paste my code :) Insert your APP_Secret there )

Comment: ya i m copying app_id and app_secret now i m  checking edited code

Comment: now error page of facebook is opening..
is there something wrong with my application??

Comment: hmm.. I'm not sure what can be wrong, with my application this code works well

Answer (score 0):

if this code works

you can set show your file inside this if

```
if($like_status)
{
    echo 'User Liked the page';
    // Place some content you wanna show to user
}
```

TEST it!!!

Like / Unlike your FB page and check what the page will return if it gives you different value then its working and inside this IF you know that user likes your page..

Comment: So what is your problem ? 

You have working script check .. just in the IF put echo of your DW link and in the ELSE echo one FB like button..

Comment: @Svetlio, read second comment for the question. As you can see, Usman is always getting "else" branch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265280/check-if-the-user-is-a-fan-of-my-facebook-page  see that

Answer (score 0):

First of all try

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
print_r($signed_request);
```

If it's empty or doesn't contain correct data, you should check your application settings (canvas url, tab url etc.)

Comment: If it's empty it means that request isn't sent to proper page, that's why you need to check app settings and make sure everything is pointing to your page (www.domain.com/page/, not facebook/app)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options client side or server side:
Here is the a link to a great tutorial on client side scripts
http://www.saschakimmel.com/2010/05/how-to-capture-clicks-on-the-facebook-like-button/

For the server side - You need to get permission from user to access his/her likes - I do not use the FB SDK, I made my own code:
- First the user has to login using this URL:

`$loginUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={$appId}&redirect_uri=   {$redirectUri}&scope={$scopeEncoded}"`;

- When the user login, FB will ask about giving permissions to this app to access Likes
- After accepting & redirecting, get the code in the url using $code = $_GET['code']
- The last step is to get the token, you need to make a request using curl to this URL

`$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={$appId}&redirect_uri={$redirectUri}&client_secret={$secretKey}&code={$code}";`

- Now, you have the token you can make curl request to user likes using this URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=$accessToken`
- Loop through the likes and find out if the user likes your page or not or use this URL:

  $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/{$yourpageId}/?access_token={$accessToken}";

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using graph API .edge.create listens to the click event of like button.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',function(response) 
{

     download();
});

FB.api("me/likes/page_id", function(response) 
{
              if ( response.data.length == 1 ) 
             { 

              //Has liked the page
              } else 
              {
               //Havent liked the page  
 }});
```

source and download script - http://www.webtuts.info/webdevelopment/facebook-download-script-2/225/